# Hard drive not available after startup

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, mount

i'm new to this forum. I have the following problem. After i boot my ubuntu 16.04 i can't use the ntfs formated windows partion in the Terminal.

```
ls /media/xxx/BE309CB8309C79DB
```

Error file or directory not found. At first I have to click on the partition in nautilius. After this i can also use the command above.

I know it's probably a beginner's question, but how is it possible to get to a status where i can use the path in the terminal right after startup?

Thanks

Comment: Have you disabled the fast boot option under windows? It's worth a try!

Comment: It sounds like your hard drive is not being mounted at start up. 

You can verify this by looking at what /etc/fstab contains (fstab handles mounting partitions)

`less /etc/fstab`

Comment: @MuaadElSharif yes fastboot is disabled.